# Dealing with ambiguous column names with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm going to do my best to layout exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm working with a real-estate database that has 5 tables related to different types of properties (residential, commercial, condo, land, etc). The database has one table called MLS that brings together all the common elements into one table across these tables. I need a view into these tables that includes mostly data from this common MLS table, but also includes some specific data from a few of the other tables.

I'm going to give an example that includes on field that exists in either the RESIDENTIAL and CONDO tables, but not the others.

In pseudo code

SELECT MLSNUMBER, (residential.CommunityAmenities OR condo.CommunityAmenities)
FROM MLSTABLE, RESIDENTIALTABLE, CONDOTABLE

Here is the actual code I'm trying, but it gives the ambiguous column name error because CommunityAmenities (and other fields) exist in multiple tables.

```
USE lsh_retsdata;

SELECT
    '',
    mls.mlsnum,
    mls.propertyclassid,
    '',
    mls.streetnumber,
    mls.streetname,
    '',
    mls.areaid,
    mls.streetletter,
    '',
    mls.StreetAddressDisplay,
    mls.remarks,
    mls.remarks,
    mls.city,
    mls.STATE,
    '',
    mls.zipcode,
    mls.countyid,
    "US",
    mls.latitude,
    mls.longitude,
    mls.listprice,
    '',
    '',
    mls.taxamount,
    '',
    totalbedrooms,
    totalfullbaths,
    mls.sqfttotal,
    '',
    mls.acres,
    mls.yearbuilt,
    mls.heatingsystem,
    mls.coolingsystem,
    heatingsource,
    mls.garagedescription,
    mls.garagecapacity,
    mls.zoning,
    '',
    mls.constructiontype,
    mls.roofmaterial,
    waterfrontdesc,
    CONCAT(mls.highschool,CHAR(13),mls.juniorhighschool),
    '',
    mls.style,
    associationfee,
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    OfficeCoListOfficeName,
    '',
    CommunityAmenities
FROM rets_property_mls mls
LEFT JOIN rets_property_mul mul
    ON mls.mlsnum = mul.mlsnum
LEFT JOIN rets_property_auc auc
    ON mls.mlsnum = auc.mlsnum
LEFT JOIN rets_property_com com
    ON mls.mlsnum = com.mlsnum
LEFT JOIN rets_property_llf llf
    ON mls.mlsnum = llf.mlsnum
LEFT JOIN rets_property_cnd cnd
    ON mls.mlsnum = cnd.mlsnum
```

Comment: a) why are you selecting empty fields? b) What errors do you get?

Comment: i suggest you use union of queries.

Comment: Just as an aside, having separate tables is insane IMHO. Have one (super) table with a "building type" column and many problems will melt away. Don't worry if you don't use all the columns for all the types.

Comment: @Bohemian thanks for the comment. I totally agree, unfortunately this data is not mine to control so I just have to try to make my own version of it. I'm essentially trying to do what you say, by creating my own master table of the data that includes extra fields. My issue being that I need 1 column called CommunityAmenities that pulls to right data based on the MLSNUM. For example MLSNUM might have an associated communityamenities field in the RES table then another will have the same field in the CND table. I'm trying to bring this data together into one field.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is (as you've noticed) that MySQL doesn't know which `CommunityAmenities` you want.

You can fix this by explicitly stating which table this field should come from:

`mul.CommunityAmenities`

(Replace mul with the appropriate table).

Comment: You have it right, however, my issue is that sometimes the data is in mul.CommunityAmenities and sometimes the data is in cnd.CommunityAmenities based on the MLSNUM listed in the main table. I need a single query to pull a field called CommunityAmenities that figures out if it should come from the CND table or the MUL table. If that makes any sense.

Comment: @AustinS How do you choose which field based on MLSNUM? Is it simply the table which matched the MLSNUM?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ALIASs to rename the columns something more meaningful :)

```
SELECT t1.CommunityAmenities AS t1CommunityAmenities,
t2. CommunityAmenities AS t2CommunityAmenities
FROM t1 left join t2 on ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you have a column that can come from more than one table but will only be in one particular table (e.g. in the condo table OR in the residential table BUT NOT BOTH) you can use
 `coalesce (condotable.communityamenities, residentialtable.communityamenities)` 
to give you the first non-null value. (In your case, the ONLY non-null value)

Comment: This seems like the solution that I want, but it refuses to work. I'm getting Unknown column in field list errors. I'm going to keep working through it. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: `SELECT rets_property_mls.mlsnum,
coalesce(rets_property_res.CommunityAmenities, rets_property_cnd.CommunityAmenities)
FROM rets_property_mls
LEFT JOIN rets_property_res res
ON rets_property_mls.mlsnum = rets_property_res.mlsnum
LEFT Join rets_property_cnd cnd
ON rets_property_mls.mlsnum = rets_property_cnd.mlsnum` This causes an error that Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'rets_property_res.CommunityAmenities' in 'field list'

Comment: Mother effing yes. I think this is going to work. Here is my edited code.. it wanted aliases bad `SELECT mls.mlsnum,
coalesce(res.CommunityAmenities, cnd.CommunityAmenities)
FROM rets_property_mls mls
LEFT JOIN rets_property_res res
ON mls.mlsnum = res.mlsnum
LEFT JOIN rets_property_cnd cnd
ON mls.mlsnum = cnd.mlsnum`

Comment: That's correct. Once you have aliased a table you have to use the alias name - you can't go back to the original name. So where you have created the alias "cnd" for rets_property_cnd by putting "LEFT Join rets_property_cnd cnd" in the "from" clause you must always refer to rets_property_cnd as just cnd.

Answer (score 0):

In your list of selected fields, you need to quality all fields to avoid this error.

For example, instead of just `CommunityAmenities` in SELECT list you should use something like `mls.CommunityAmenities`. Otherwise, server does not know which exact table you meant - you joined many of them, and they all have this field.